# Why is my Android App crashing when I'm trying to access string resources?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm doing the HelloLinearLayout tutorial, but using string resources instead of hard coding the strings directly into the XML like the tutorial. When I run the app using string resources, it crashes immediately. When I hard code the strings into the XML code, everything works fine. Any ideas as to why my app is crashing? Thanks

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/box1text"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@string/box1color"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="@string/box1weight"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/box2text"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@string/box2color"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="@string/box2weight"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/box3text"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@string/box3color"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="@string/box2weight"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/box4text"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@string/box4color"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="@string/box4weight"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloLinearLayoutActivity!</string>
        <string name="app_name">HelloLinearLayout</string>
        <string name="box1text">red</string>
        <string name="box1color">#aa0000</string>
        <string name="box1weight">1</string>
        <string name="box2text">green</string>
        <string name="box2color">#00aa00</string>
        <string name="box2weight">1</string>
        <string name="box3text">blue</string>
        <string name="box3color">#0000aa</string>
        <string name="box3weight">1</string>
        <string name="box4text">yellow</string>
        <string name="box4color">#aaaa00</string>
        <string name="box4weight">1</string>
    </resources>
```

**hellolinearlayoutactivity.java**

```
package com.example.hellolinearlayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloLinearLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat output of the crash?

Comment: and are you short one `</LinearLayout>` closing tag?

Comment: You did not close your parent LinearLayout buddy.check it.

Answer (score 4):

You can not set background color as strings.
Create an XML file at res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
   <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
  <color name="box4color">#aaaa00</color>
</resources>
```

Then use like below.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/box4color"
    android:textColor="@color/translucent_red"
    android:text="Hello"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I this this is because of the `android:background="@string/box1color"`. Why because the background attribute accommodate the integer values in the form of HEXADECIMAL .But you used string resources. I think this is the problem. But I am not sure... As per my knowledge i guessed this. If this content have wrong information please excuse.

Comment: you are correct. Taking the xml files as given results in android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown> which is the line containing the "@string/box1color"

For some reason it tries to convert the hex value to a drawable